# Why can't I send JSON from Ruby to Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, phantomjs

I am using [the PhantomJS gem](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem) to call PhantomJS scripts from Ruby.

I've used this gem successfully in my app when I need to send HTML to a PhantomJS script that I'm calling.

However, it's failing when I try to send JSON to a PhantomJS script that I'm calling.

The PhantomJS script I am calling is [PhantomJS-Google-Charts](https://github.com/pstephan1187/PhantomJS-Google-Charts).

I have modified the first few lines of the script to read:

```
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var jsonData = fs.open(system.args[1], 'r'); // also tried 'rb'

// exports.generateChart = function(jsonData, callback){
    var page = require('webpage').create();

    page.viewportSize = {width: jsonData.options.width, height: jsonData.options.height};
```

I made these few changes because (a) after trying and failing to send the JSON to the script directly as an argument I read that [in situations like my own the only way to send JSON to PhantomJS is to save it to a file and then read it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/mqN55Zo-OfY), and (b) I'm not calling this script as a module from another JavaScript script -- I'm calling it directly from Ruby -- which means `export` is not available to me.

In Ruby, I'm doing this:

```
data = {"type" => "PieChart", "options" => {"title" => "Type of Fruit Eaten", "width" => "400", "height" => "300", "is3D" => true, "pieSliceText" => "value"},"columns" => {"Type" => "string", "Eaten" => "number"}, "rows" => {"Bananas" => 4, "Apples" => 2, "Oranges" => 6, "Mangoes" => 3}}.to_json
require 'tempfile'
file = Tempfile.new("foo")
file.write(data)
file.rewind
Phantomjs.run("./app/assets/javascripts/googleCharts.js", file.path)
```

Why, then, am I getting this error:

```
"TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'jsonData.options.width')\n\n  ./app/assets/javascripts/googleCharts.js:43\n"
```

BTW, line 43 (referred to in the error) is:

```
page.viewportSize = {width: jsonData.options.width, height: jsonData.options.height};
```

When I open the tempfile in Textmate it looks like this:

```
{"type":"PieChart","options":{"title":"Type of Fruit Eaten","width":"400","height":"300","is3D":true,"pieSliceText":"value"},"columns":{"Type":"string","Eaten":"number"},"rows":{"Bananas":4,"Apples":2,"Oranges":6,"Mangoes":3}}
```

When I paste that into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), it validates.

Why I run the script at the PhantomJS command line (pasting in the file's path rather than calling it from `system.args`), I get this error:

```
'page.viewportSize = {width: jsonData.options.width, height: jsonData.options.height};' is a cyclic structure
```

At that point, if I just type `jsonData.options.width`, I get:

```
'jsonData.options.width' is a cyclic structure
```

If I just type jsonData, I get:

```
undefined
```

Comment: When supplying data, give us the very minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything more wastes space and makes it harder to work with.

Comment: What happens if you use `file.puts data` instead of using `file.write(data)`?

Comment: same result as `file.write(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.

The steps are:

(1) Do not change `googleCharts.js` (unlike what I've written above). Instead, you use `googleCharts.js` exactly as per https://github.com/pstephan1187/PhantomJS-Google-Charts

(2) Place googleCharts.js in `/app/assets/javascripts` unless you want to modify the code below

(3) Call `googleCharts.js` from the following JavaScript script:

```
var GC = require('./googleCharts.js');

var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = system.args[1];
var opened = fs.open(path, "r");
var data = fs.read(path);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

GC.generateChart(jsonData, function(svgHtml){
    console.log(svgHtml);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

(4) Call that script `trigger.js` and place it in `/app/assets/javascripts`, unless you want to modify the following code

(5) Install the PhantomJS gem https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem

(6) Call the whole lot with the following Ruby:

```
data = {"type" => "PieChart", "options" => {"title" => "Type of Fruit Eaten", "width" => "400", "height" => "300", "is3D" => true, "pieSliceText" => "value"},"columns" => {"Type" => "string", "Eaten" => "number"}, "rows" => {"Bananas" => 4, "Apples" => 2, "Oranges" => 6, "Mangoes" => 3}}.to_json
require 'tempfile'
file = Tempfile.new(['a', '.txt'], "#{Rails.root}/tmp")
file.write(data)
File.chmod(444, file.path)
file.rewind
Phantomjs.run("./app/assets/javascripts/trigger.js", file.path)
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a fork designed to show it all in action:

https://github.com/snoblenet/PhantomJS-Google-Charts-Ruby